# Matplotlib add Labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, numbers, bar-chart

just a simple question from a newby...
I would add numbers at the end of this bar plot ( values of the dictionaries as a labels ) which is the correct sintax?
Thanks

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_excel('aspire_2408.xls')

started=len(df.loc[df['Aspire year-end reflection (FY22)'] == 
'Started'])

completed = len(df.loc[df['Aspire year-end reflection (FY22)'] == 
'Complete'])

not_started = len(df.loc[df['Aspire year-end reflection (FY22)'] == 'Not 
Started'])


data = {'Not Started':not_started, 'Started':started, 
'Completed':completed}

courses = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())
  
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
 
# creating the bar plot

plt.bar(courses, values, color =['red','blue','green'],
        width = 0.4)
plt.xlabel("Year End Review Completion Status")
plt.ylabel("No Users")
plt.title("Aspire Year End Review")


plt.show()
```

Comment: can you make your example reproducible? `not_started` isn't defined

Comment: not_started = len(df.loc[df['Aspire year-end reflection (FY22)'] == 'Not Started'])

Comment: started=len(df.loc[df['Aspire year-end reflection (FY22)'] == 'Started'])

Comment: complete = len(df.loc[df['Aspire year-end reflection (FY22)'] == 'Complete'])

Comment: I would like to add at the end of the bar the len of the three labels

Comment: thanks - can you add that to the question?

Comment: also, you haven't defined `df` - please post an example that's fully reproducible

Comment: done, hope is it clear

Comment: What @ignoring_gravity is trying to say is that we don't have access to your dataframe because it comes from an Excel file on your computer. We don't want you to show where you are getting your data from but what your data looks like. The best way to do this is create code to make a small example of your data (eg `df= pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5]})`) or a the least a markdown table of your data. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that's what you meant. I simply created a new list for the x ticks and added it as the xticks on the plt.

Edit: If you want to display the number on top of the bar, there is a built-in bar_label in matplotlib 3.4.0

```
data = {'Not Started':not_started, 'Started':started, 'Completed':completed}
courses = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())
x_labels = list(a + ' ' + str(b) for (a, b) in zip(courses, values))

# creating the bar plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
bars = ax.bar(courses, values, color =['red','blue','green'],
    width = 0.4)
ax.bar_label(bars, fmt="%d", fontsize=26, rotation=0, padding=3)
plt.bar(courses, values, color =['red','blue','green'],
        width = 0.4)
plt.xticks(courses, x_labels)
plt.xlabel("Year End Review Completion Status")
plt.ylabel("No Users")
plt.title("Aspire Year End Review")


plt.show()
```

Comment: Great! It works...it could be better if the figures has shown at the end up of the bar